# Access Request Body by name in c#

Tags: c#

I receive a redirect from a shop and this redirect contains this:

```
    Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 1023
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Origin: null
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.39 Safari/535.19
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://republica.ipapercms.dk/LandFritid/LF/LFaviser2012/Tilbudsavis32012/iPaper.swf?build=1.0.4433.19406
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __utma=83547913.319162761.1326373492.1326373492.1327614257.2; __utmz=83547913.1326373492.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH=07F9D44B16738D2B133AAD3F6101F5D01ED26F236C01792206AA4AB8E325868D020B5B2212BE280F9905D0708431E2820B4935C75E361EA6485418420E3B63280D8F81454B52C99D79B37BEEFC207128796E3BE846F84FEF8D3AF9AAB80AA45FB76ACB3EA11EF1F2CF46B11FCD1B00309E6C3C5F70C07F54851E52207368034CBD38176A4EB4DD48C0D2CB6C17D35A4F5E61C4491DB8D890DCFA4D69BCA44096076CFCFC2B6B1247D84BFD76DD8F90FFEA20392EFED238530D6E21F7CD24C5093427A07757324E4FA8F25A36FDE35942; Nop.customer=f2d43727-9c52-4c9f-a199-6647d507e40b

basket=%3Cshop%20paper%3D%22%2FLandFritid%2FLF%2FLFaviser2012%2FTilbudsavis32012%2F%22%3E%0A%20%20%3Citem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Camount%3E1%3C%2Famount%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cproductid%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B810570%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fproductid%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B36%2E33%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdescription%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BVed%20K%C3%B8b%20af%20minimum%203%20stk%2E%20%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BBrilliant%20Kalk%2015%20kg%2E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%20%20%3Citem%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Camount%3E1%3C%2Famount%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cproductid%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B863254%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fproductid%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cprice%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B499%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fprice%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cdescription%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5B15%2B3%20kg%2E%20Hundefoder%20til%20voksne%2E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fdescription%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cname%3E%3C%21%5BCDATA%5BRoyal%20Canin%20Maxi%20Adult%2015%2B3%20kg%2E%5D%5D%3E%3C%2Fname%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Fitem%3E%0A%3C%2Fshop%3E
```

As you see there is a `basket` body parameter containing this encoded xml.

I've tried to access it using Request.InputStream:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
String sXMLRequest = reader.ReadToEnd();
xd.LoadXml(sXMLRequest);
```

but seems to fail:

```
System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1. at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseRootLevelWhitespace() at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader) at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml) at Nop.Web.Controllers.ShoppingCartController.IPaperCheckout()
```

Do you know any other way to access this?

Comment: If I'm reading this right, what you're trying to load isn't XML at this point -- it's still encoded when you attempt to parse it as XML.

Comment: @George: I tried to decode it `xd.LoadXml(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(sXMLRequest));` but still have the same issue...

Comment: @Cristian: It's `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (look at the header), not HTML-escaped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of reading the `Request` stream I would suggest to access the `FormCollection` instead e.g. `Request.Form["basket"]` the form collection is properly decoded so you do not have to cope with decoding:

```
<shop paper="/LandFritid/LF/LFaviser2012/Tilbudsavis32012/">
  <item>
    <amount>1</amount>
    <productid><![CDATA[810570]]></productid>
    <price><![CDATA[36.33]]></price>
    <description><![CDATA[Ved Køb af minimum 3 stk. ]]></description>
    <name><![CDATA[Brilliant Kalk 15 kg.]]></name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <amount>1</amount>
    <productid><![CDATA[863254]]></productid>
    <price><![CDATA[499]]></price>
    <description><![CDATA[15+3 kg. Hundefoder til voksne.]]></description>
    <name><![CDATA[Royal Canin Maxi Adult 15+3 kg.]]></name>
  </item>
</shop>
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be closer:) The single exception I have now: ` A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (basket="<shop paper="/LandFr..."). ` ...I know in a web form context to solve this, but how I can to it right here because the context is MVC...

Comment: Asp.net assumes that you are trying to do an xss attack (xml has the suspicious lt gt tag). You need to set `ValidateRequest="false"`.

Answer (score 2):

The value of the basket is the following:

```
<shop paper="/LandFritid/LF/LFaviser2012/Tilbudsavis32012/">
  <item>
    <amount>1</amount>
    <productid><![CDATA[810570]]></productid>
    <price><![CDATA[36.33]]></price>
    <description><![CDATA[Ved KÃ¸b af minimum 3 stk. ]]></description>
    <name><![CDATA[Brilliant Kalk 15 kg.]]></name>
  </item>
  <item>
    <amount>1</amount>
    <productid><![CDATA[863254]]></productid>
    <price><![CDATA[499]]></price>
    <description><![CDATA[15+3 kg. Hundefoder til voksne.]]></description>
    <name><![CDATA[Royal Canin Maxi Adult 15+3 kg.]]></name>
  </item>
</shop>
```

you may need to append this at the top in order to load it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

also, the value that you are load may not be decoded after you read it. Check the string where you are loading it and if it is still looks that same as posted, it is not decoded.